# Can not create hotspot after upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless

When i use ubuntu 11.04 i have problem with create a hotspot.
Now im upgrade system to ubuntu 11.10 and i can not create it.
When i try create hotspot, network manager in loop ask me for key, but i promt it...

Any idea?

syslog info:

```
 wpa_supplicant[1099]: Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
 wpa_supplicant[1099]: Trying to associate with SSID 'hotspot'
 kernel: [  105.799013] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_config: change monitor mode: false (implement)
 kernel: [  105.799025] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
 wpa_supplicant[1099]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
 wpa_supplicant[1099]: Association request to the driver failed
 kernel: [  105.801088] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
 kernel: [  105.801765] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: Trying to associate with SSID 'hotspot'
 hotspot kernel: [  115.859235] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_config: change monitor mode: false (implement)
 hotspot kernel: [  115.859248] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
 hotspot kernel: [  115.859770] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: Association request to the driver failed
 hotspot kernel: [  115.861261] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: Trying to associate with SSID 'hotspot'
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
 hotspot wpa_supplicant[1099]: Association request to the driver failed
 hotspot kernel: [  125.929227] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_config: change monitor mode: false (implement)
 hotspot kernel: [  125.929234] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
 hotspot kernel: [  125.929740] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
 hotspot kernel: [  125.930379] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <warn> No agents were available for this request.
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (hotspot)
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <info> Marking connection 'hotspot' invalid.
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed.
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
 hotspot NetworkManager[949]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

To fix this, I added the following three lines to the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist brcmutil
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/863799/comments/3

Thanks for help...